# getUserCache and getUserProperties are these for effective or active users?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to figure out whether these 2 methods refer to the effective user of the script or the active user of the script. Unfortunately I could not found any documentation in regard.

I would guess that it relates to the effective user (the one who under his authority the script is running) rather than the active user (the one who initiated the script).

If anyone can shed some light on this or can point me to the right documentation it would be great!

Comment: Maybe you could do a test by running the script simultaneously in two different browsers.  That way you can be logged in on one browser, and using the script anonymously on the other browser.  Shouldn't be to hard.  If no one answers, you can answer your own question.

Comment: Looks like you can use the Session Class to get the active and effective user.  So you could use that to test what the script returns versus the actual usage.  [Google Documentation Link - Session Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getEffectiveUser())

Comment: Thanks. It definitely refers to the concepts mentioned in regard to session and I was aware of that too. I was looking to see if someone already has the answers to save me time in doing it myself. I am also concerned with whether there is any formal documentation that answer my question as I want to make sure that whatever the current functionality is it won't won't change on the fly.