# Do i need to declare multiple times global variables used by multiple scripts in one project?

Tags: google-apps-script

Dumb question but I can't find an answer, I have a project with multiple scripts where I use global variables in multiple functions, do I need to declare the global variables in all of the scripts or can I just leave them in one script for them to be used by all fo the other scripts ?

All of the variables are used to define a line and column in spreadsheet in case that the spreadsheet needs to be modified (to avoid looking for the values in multiple functions).

Thank you.

Comment: All `.gs` files in a project share the same namespace. This is why from `A.gs` you can use function `b()` which you have implemented on `B.gs`.

Comment: @tehhowch thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use global variable instead of passing parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417098/can-i-use-global-variable-instead-of-passing-parameters)